# Very slow transfer rate to USB drive

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, transfer-rate

Freshly installed Windows 10 on an older Dell Precision M6500 with USB 3.0 ports.

Trying to transfer 42GB of pictures and videos to a 64GB USB 2.0 drive. It’s taking a very long time and transfer rate barely reaches 1MB it’s usually sitting around 500-800KB. Occasionally it’ll jump to 2-5MB/s but it’s short lived only a few seconds.

Trying to update usb drivers but says none available or best ones already installed.

Would it be an issue with the flash drive being it’s 2.0 and a cheap Amazon $8 SamData drive? Just don’t remember this laptop being so slow transferring via usb before

Comment: USB2 is limited to ~35MB/s at best, and cheap awful drives are slow. I have an old drive from years ago and it peaks out at 5MB/s write.

Comment: "Would it be an issue with the flash drive being it’s 2.0 and a cheap Amazon $8 SamData drive? J" Yes, cheap drives are slow as molasses.

Comment: Additionally, transfer of many small files is slower yet, because of continual writing to the files system index. You might compare speed of transfer of 1,000 files vs. one zip archive with all files.